# Draw polyline with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm needing to draw a polyline through several points with an ffmpeg command. Is there a simple way to do this other than creating a canvas and rotating for each line segment (like in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1142470/ffmpeg-draw-a-line-from-point-to-point/1142528#1142528))?

[Polyline Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNak3.jpg)

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf drawbox=x=10:y=10:w=692:h=1:color=red output.mp4
```

Coordinates (x,y): `(100,100), (200,300), (300,200), (400, 500)`

Comment: Have you considered using a more suitable tool to do this? Maybe even Libreoffice or dia.

Comment: All I've considered is drawing a polyline in a separate image file with Imagemagick, then using ffmpeg to overlay it. My reasoning behind keeping it all within ffmpeg is mainly for scale and performance reasons. Could you elaborate how the other apps could be better suited toward this?

Comment: FFmpeg doesn't have a generic geometry source filter, so any polyline would have to be generated using many pixel+rotation filters. Performance wise, it would be quicker to create this elsewhere as an image and then overlay it.